# How do i change the javafx intellij template to my own template if i create a new javafx application?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I do not want to use the Intellij IDEA template anymore when creating javafx programs. I want to use my own template because I can work a lot better with it. Here is an example of what I mean.

Intellij template, I do not want to use this anymore:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

My template, I want to use this template:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a user defined template with quite simple steps.

- create a new project using the build-in `JavaFX` template
- amend the `Main` class with your changes
- in the `Tools` menu select `Save project as template...`
  [image]

- save it e.g. as `JavaFX own`

[image]
[image]

- after that it will be available in the new project wizard in category `User-defined`

[image]
[image]

Comment: @o7295704 You need to start the new project wizard. Just the first entry in the menu `Project...`.

Comment: I have followed the steps, but I do not see any "user-defined"

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: @o7295704 Please have a look to the updated answer. I added some screenshots.

Comment: Adding to the answer is worth noting, that with Intellij 2018 and 2019 you cannot create a project with the JavaFX template, and save as new template. At least it didn't work for me. I had to create a new java 11 project, and build javaFX project from scratch and then save as template.

Comment: @kodaman Just verified with a fresh installed IntelliJ 2019.1.2, the described steps still work.

Comment: Yup, I had latest version fresh install on windows and it didn't work by using javafx template. Win10, and 7.

Comment: Just thought I'd let everyone know since there's lots of people asking, and I'm afraid this is why. I dunno if is a bug, documentation just says like your steps and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @kodaman I executed the steps on Ubuntu and OpendJDK 11 as only (automatically) configured Java SDK in IntelliJ.

Comment: On Intellij 2019.1.1 latest on Win7 or 10 it doesn't work, must likely a bug for sure. Work around is how I described above. Must likely why OP never got it to work. Though he didn't put his OS.